# data not being saved in firebase database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I am just starting out with Firebase and have managed to send data to a Firebase Realtime Database. The problem is that some times it works and sometimes not. I am struggling to understand why.

Here is a code snippet

```js
var pq_data = jsPsych.data.get().values();
  for (var ix= 0; ix < pq_data.length; ix++){
    var object=pq_data[ix];
    var pq_boo = pq_database.ref(subj_id +ix.toString()+'/').update(object)

  }
```

As I say this works sometimes but not always and I understand that it may have something to do with the code completing before the write operations have(?)
I have read but do not clearly understand advice about onCompletion and I am still in the dark. I need to make sure each object is written to the database - is this possible and if so how?

Very much a beginner,
Philip.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Import Admin SDK
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

// Get a database reference to our blog
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("server/saving-data/fireblog");
```

First, create a database reference to your user data. Then use set() / setValue() to save a user object to the database with the user's username, full name, and birthday. You can pass set a string, number, boolean, null, array or any JSON object. Passing null will remove the data at the specified location. In this case you'll pass it an object:

```
var usersRef = ref.child("users");
usersRef.set({
  alanisawesome: {
    date_of_birth: "June 23, 1912",
    full_name: "Alan Turing"
  },
  gracehop: {
    date_of_birth: "December 9, 1906",
    full_name: "Grace Hopper"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this Yes For brevity I didn't show all the code and so I have access to the database. The problem is with sending data to it. Sometimes it works and sometimes not.

I now realise this is related to my failure to deal with Promises. I have now some understanding of these but still need to make sure that the data gets captured in the database. SO even though the Promise may return an Error I still need to re-send the data so that it will get written to the database. Still not sure whether this is advisable or even possible.